# Elif bad input on trinket.io

Tags: python

I'm making a simple Python Rock Paper Scissors game for a school project. I'm new to Python but I'm getting the error "ParseError: bad input on line 12 in main.py" here is my code:

```
import random


choice = input("Welcome to rock paper scissors! You go first.")
choice = choice.upper()
a = [1, 2, 3]

b = random.choice(a)

if b == 1:
print("My choice: ROCK")
elif b == 2:
  print("My choice: PAPER")
    elif b = 3:
      print("My choice: SCISSORS")



print("Your choice: " + choice)


if choice == b:

 print "Draw. Play again!"
```

So it's the *Elif* statements that are giving me trouble, but I don't see how they could possibly be wrong, I've looked everywhere.

Comment: Is that your indentation? There are some lines wrong. E.g. indent the print statement before the first elif properly.

Comment: What's your error? It could be due to the indentation of your print("my choice: ROCK") statement

Comment: Indentation, always indentation (`if ` / `elif`). Be careful in Python it is very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong: the `elif` must be at the same level. Besides, you wrote `elif b = 3`, but it should be `elif b == 3`.

```
if b == 1:
    print("My choice: ROCK")
elif b == 2:
    print("My choice: PAPER")
elif b == 3:
    print("My choice: SCISSORS")
```

Note that the code as you posted raises an `IdentationError` in a Python 3 interpreter.

Comment: Thanks! Works now. I'm new to Python but now I know that indentation matters.